# Yii2 sharing namespaces between view and controller

Tags: php, namespaces, yii2, php-5.5

I have my application controllers configured with namespace as following:

```
 use yii\helpers\Html;
```

When i try to access the Html class within the view: I get an exception, and have to re-declare the use statement.

Can i share the controller / view namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controllers and views are differrent parts of your application. So you should declare `use`s in both controllers and views. This is not a bug, it's a common practice.

Comment: didnt say it was a bug :) just wondering since its tedious... re-declaring HTML in all views, but i'll find a workaround for that (probably a custom class)